# nodejs: async/await. Объясните новичку пару моментов

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, асинхронность

Будут ли эти записи равны? Это ведь то же самое, правильно я понимаю?

```
func() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ///
        resolve();
    })
}

async func() {
    ///
    return true;
}
```

---

И вот эти записи. Я так понимаю, вторая будет выполняться быстрее, в несколько потоков. А первая запись - будет постоянно ожидать выполнения функции getProducts. Верно?

```
 for(var i = 0; i<=1000; i++) {
var res = await getProduct();   
console.log(res);
}

for(var i = 0; i<=1000; i++) {
getProduct().then(res=>{
    console.log(res)
})}
```

---

Как создать ожидание выполнения асинхронной функции? (await - не решение). Хочу сделать через переменную this.progress. Но не понимаю как. Пока this.progress не будет равняться false, не выполнять `console.log('stop')`

Есть такой вывод:

```
2 add
3 add
4 add
stop
2 commit
3 commit
4 commit
```

А надо:

```
2 add
3 add
4 add
2 commit
3 commit
4 commit
stop
```

Вот тестовый код:

```
 async run() {
    var data = [{id: 1, name: 'Alex', value: 18}, {id: 5, name: 'Sergey', value: 10}, {
        id: 6,
        name: 'Elena',
        value: 90
    }];
    var row = 2;
    this.progress = false;
    for (var item in data) {
        console.log(row+" add");
        ws.getCell("A" + row).value = data[item].id;
        ws.getCell("B" + row).value = data[item].name;
        ws.getCell("C" + row).value = data[item].value;
        //ws.getCell("D" + row).value = this.getRand();
        this.setStat(row, ws).then(res=>{
            ws.getRow(res).commit();
            console.log(res+" comitt"); 
        });
        row++;
    }
    console.log("stop");
}
async setStat(row, ws) {
    this.progress = true;
    var w = ["D", "E", "F"];
    var b = [];
    for(var ww in w) {
        var res = await this.getRand();
        ws.getCell(w[ww]+row).value = res;
        b.push(res);
    }
    return row;
}
```

Comment: А почему `await` не решение? Перед `this.setStat(row.ws)` поставить и тогда вывод будет как нужный.

Comment: `await Promise.all(data.map(async item => {...}))`

Comment: @RTK, потому что тогда будет  обрабатываться все очень долго. Надо спарсить 3 млн товаров. Если я поставлю там await, то и за несколько дней не соберу такое кол-во.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Будут ли эти записи равны? Это ведь то же самое, правильно я понимаю?

В одном случае вернется true, в другом - undefined, так что не совсем

[Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) позволяет параллельно запустить несколько промисов и продолжить выполнение, когда они все будут выполнены

```
const promises = [];
for (var item in data) {
    console.log(row+" add");
    ws.getCell("A" + row).value = data[item].id;
    ws.getCell("B" + row).value = data[item].name;
    ws.getCell("C" + row).value = data[item].value;
    //ws.getCell("D" + row).value = this.getRand();
    promises.push(
        this.setStat(row, ws).then(res=>{
            ws.getRow(res).commit();
            console.log(res+" comitt"); 
        });
    );
    row++;
}
Promise.all(promises).then(
    () => {console.log("stop");}
);
```

Comment: Promise.all не запускает промисы

Comment: Проверил код, все работает. Спасибо!